# XAML binding silverlight

Tags: silverlight, xaml, binding

I have a user control defined as follows:

```
<UserControl ...
......
x:name="StartPage">

<ToggleButton  
x:Name="FullScreenToggle" 
Content="{Binding ElementName=StartPage,Path=FullScreenState,Mode=OneWay}" />

</UserControl>
```

in the code behind:

```
public String FullScreenState
{
            get;
            set;
}
```

However for some reason the ToggleButton's Content property doesn't pick up the property.
Any ideas?

Comment: +1 for showing it is possible to do element binding to your code behind :)

Comment: How did it work ? IMO,This can't work like that.Because while rendering UserControl you can't bind a property on an absent object.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Your binding is perfectly valid, but you need to use an updatable property or the view will not be notified of the property changing.

Basically it needs to call PropertyChanged with the details of the changed property:

```
private string _fullScreenState;
public string FullScreenState
{
    get { return _fullScreenState; }
    set
    {
        if (_fullScreenState != value)
        {
            _fullScreenState = value;
            if (this.PropertyChanged != null)
            {
                this.PropertyChanged(this, new PropertyChangedEventArgs("FullScreenState"));
            }
        }
    }
}
```

This means your control has to implement INotifyPropertyChanged:

```
public partial class SilverlightControl1 : UserControl, INotifyPropertyChanged
```

and provide the event handler:

```
public event PropertyChangedEventHandler PropertyChanged;
```

*As mentioned by *tam*, you can also use a dependency property if you want to extend your control for use in other controls. Horses for courses :)

Comment: The object state is not created yet. Before ctor's creation how can it be possible ? You are binding to an absent object. Is it possible ?

Comment: @ Davut Gürbüz: Please explain what are you saying? An empty object is constructed, as the XAML is parsed, *before* its values are serialised from the XAML content.

Answer (score 0):

You will have to set the DataContext of the UserControl:

```
DataContext="{Binding RelativeSource={RelativeSource Self}}"
```

I believe you'll also have to remove the "ElementName" property from the binding statement.
Then, you should should be able to bind to properties in the code behind.

Comment: The element binding to the StartPage control itself is perfectly valid and works. He just forgot to use an updatable property. I like your binding example though.

Comment: @HiTech, good point...I was assuming his property was being set in the constructor rather than afterwards, which, in that case, would need the PropertyChanged event as you pointed out.

Answer (score 0):

you can also define your property as a dependency property, this would give you the flexibility to be able to bind to it later on in a bigger control

ex:

```
    public int MyProperty
    {
        get { return (int)GetValue(MyPropertyProperty); }
        set { SetValue(MyPropertyProperty, value); }
    }

    // Using a DependencyProperty as the backing store for MyProperty.  This enables animation, styling, binding, etc...
    public static readonly DependencyProperty MyPropertyProperty =
        DependencyProperty.Register("MyProperty", typeof(int), typeof(ownerclass), new UIPropertyMetadata(0));
```